# Efficiently iterate over nested lists to find sum

Tags: python, iteration, nested-lists

I have an array of arrays and want to check if the sum equals 40. The problem is that the array has around 270,000,000 elements and doing in sequentially is out of the picture. The problem that I am having is finding the sums in a reasonable amount of time. I have ran this program overnight and it is still running in the morning. How can I make this program more efficient and run decently fast?

Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np


def cartesianProduct(arrays):
    la = arrays.shape[0]
    arr = np.empty([la] + [a.shape[0] for a in arrays], dtype="int32")
    for i, a in enumerate(np.ix_(*arrays)):
        arr[i, ...] = a
    return arr.reshape(la, -1).T


rows = np.array(
    [
        [2, 15, 23, 19, 3, 2, 3, 27, 20, 11, 27, 10, 19, 10, 13, 10],
        [22, 9, 5, 10, 5, 1, 24, 2, 10, 9, 7, 3, 12, 24, 10, 9],
        [16, 0, 17, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 10, 0, 15, 0, 6, 0, 9, 0],
        [11, 27, 14, 5, 5, 7, 8, 24, 8, 3, 6, 15, 22, 6, 1, 1],
        [10, 0, 2, 0, 22, 0, 2, 0, 17, 0, 15, 0, 14, 0, 5, 0],
        [1, 6, 10, 6, 10, 2, 6, 10, 4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 8, 6, 3],
        [6, 0, 13, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0],
    ],
    dtype="int32",
)

product = cartesianProduct(rows)
combos = []

for row in product:
    if sum(row) == 40:
        combos.append(row)

print(combos)
```

Comment: There are 5,053,776 combos with sum 40. What do you want to do with them?

Comment: *array of arrays and want to check if the sum equals 40* The sum of what exactly?

Comment: @DaniMesejo. The sum of each row in product array, I suppose.

Comment: Use something like `branch and cut` algorithm to avoid evaluating all impossible combinations. If in a row, you have 27 and 24, it is useless to evaluate sum of all rows that contain them so you can cut your tree and save time. Read [this](https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom.html)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode how did you get that number

Comment: @DaniMesejo the sum of each row

Comment: @MaxwellHay I computed it. What about my question?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode at the moment I just want to print them out. How did you do it though? Code? Algorithim used?

Comment: Just a little DP.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is called NP-hard. Look into "dynamic programming" and "subset sum"

Examples:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/
- https://www.techiedelight.com/subset-sum-problem/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments one way to optimize this is to check if the sum of a sub array already exceeds your threshold (40 in this case). and as another optimization to this you can even sort the arrays incrementally from largest to smallest.

Check [heapq.nlargest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) for incremental partial sorting.